# Edit Text is force closing app

Tags: android, json, android-listview, android-edittext

I've managed to solve my JSONObject problem by encoding my edit text but my app still force crashes.  This time my logcat says I have called my edit text in the wrong thread, So I was just hoping somebody with better experience than me can give me some advice and tell me what can be done to solve this problem.

```
08-05 19:07:36.617: E/AndroidRuntime(772): FATAL EXCEPTION: AsyncTask #2
08-05 19:07:36.617: E/AndroidRuntime(772): java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occured while executing doInBackground()
08-05 19:07:36.617: E/AndroidRuntime(772):  at android.os.AsyncTask$3.done(AsyncTask.java:299)
08-05 19:07:36.617: E/AndroidRuntime(772):  at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.finishCompletion(FutureTask.java:352)
08-05 19:07:36.617: E/AndroidRuntime(772):  at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.setException(FutureTask.java:219)
08-05 19:07:36.617: E/AndroidRuntime(772):  at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:239)
08-05 19:07:36.617: E/AndroidRuntime(772):  at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:230)
08-05 19:07:36.617: E/AndroidRuntime(772):  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1080)
08-05 19:07:36.617: E/AndroidRuntime(772):  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:573)
08-05 19:07:36.617: E/AndroidRuntime(772):  at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856)
08-05 19:07:36.617: E/AndroidRuntime(772): Caused by: android.view.ViewRootImpl$CalledFromWrongThreadException: Only the original thread that created a view hierarchy can touch its views.
08-05 19:07:36.617: E/AndroidRuntime(772):  at android.view.ViewRootImpl.checkThread(ViewRootImpl.java:4746)
08-05 19:07:36.617: E/AndroidRuntime(772):  at android.view.ViewRootImpl.requestLayout(ViewRootImpl.java:823)
08-05 19:07:36.617: E/AndroidRuntime(772):  at android.view.View.requestLayout(View.java:15473)
08-05 19:07:36.617: E/AndroidRuntime(772):  at android.view.ViewGroup.addView(ViewGroup.java:3208)
08-05 19:07:36.617: E/AndroidRuntime(772):  at android.view.ViewGroup.addView(ViewGroup.java:3186)
08-05 19:07:36.617: E/AndroidRuntime(772):  at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.generateLayout(PhoneWindow.java:2813)
08-05 19:07:36.617: E/AndroidRuntime(772):  at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.installDecor(PhoneWindow.java:2875)
08-05 19:07:36.617: E/AndroidRuntime(772):  at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.getDecorView(PhoneWindow.java:1568)
08-05 19:07:36.617: E/AndroidRuntime(772):  at android.view.Window.findViewById(Window.java:900)
08-05 19:07:36.617: E/AndroidRuntime(772):  at android.app.Activity.findViewById(Activity.java:1839)
08-05 19:07:36.617: E/AndroidRuntime(772):  at com.theproblemsolver.ListView$LoadAllData.doInBackground(ListView.java:90)
08-05 19:07:36.617: E/AndroidRuntime(772):  at com.theproblemsolver.ListView$LoadAllData.doInBackground(ListView.java:1)
08-05 19:07:36.617: E/AndroidRuntime(772):  at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:287)
08-05 19:07:36.617: E/AndroidRuntime(772):  at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:234)
08-05 19:07:36.617: E/AndroidRuntime(772):  ... 4 more
```

MainActivity:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    EditText et;
    Button getanswer;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        Button getanswer = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
        getanswer.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            //} catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                //e.printStackTrace();
            //}
            Intent i = new Intent(MainActivity.this, ListView.class);
            startActivity(i);
        }


        });
    } 
}
```

ListViewActivity:

```
public class ListView extends ListActivity {

    private ProgressDialog pDialog;

    JSONParsser jParser = new JSONParsser();
    ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> questionList;





    //JSONObject json = jParser.getJSONFromURI(URI);

     final String TAG_RESULTS = "results";
     final String TAG_QUESTION_SUBJECT = "Subject";
     final String TAG_QUESTION_NUMANSWERS = "NumAnswers";
     final String TAG_QUESTION = "Question";
     final String TAG_QUESTION_CONTENT = "Content";
     final String TAG_QUESTION_CHOSENANSWER = "ChosenAnswer";
     final String TAG_ANSWERS = "Answers";
     final String TAG_ANSWER = "Answer";    
     final String TAG_ANSWERS_CONTENT = "Content";      

            JSONArray results;


    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState); 
        //setContentView(R.layout.listview);        

        //questionList = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();



    new LoadAllData().execute();
        }

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

        if (resultCode == 100) {
            Intent intent = getIntent();
            startActivity(intent);
            finish();
        }
    }

    class LoadAllData extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {


        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();
            pDialog = new ProgressDialog(ListView.this);
            pDialog.setMessage("Loading Data. Please wait...");
            pDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
            pDialog.setCancelable(false);
            pDialog.show();
            if (pDialog != null && pDialog.isShowing()) pDialog.dismiss();

        }

        protected String doInBackground(String... args) {

            EditText et = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText1);
            String searchTerm = et.getText().toString().trim();
            try {
                String query = URLEncoder.encode(searchTerm, "utf-8");
                String URL = "http://example.com/json";
                JSONObject jObj = jParser.readJSONFeed(URL);
                try {
                    results = jObj.getJSONArray(TAG_RESULTS);

                    for(int i = 0; i < results.length(); i++) {
                           JSONObject r = results.getJSONObject(i);

                           JSONObject Question = r.getJSONObject(TAG_QUESTION);
                           String Subject = Question.getString(TAG_QUESTION_SUBJECT);
                           String NumAnswers = Question.getString(TAG_QUESTION_NUMANSWERS);
                           String ChosenAnswers= Question.getString(TAG_QUESTION_CHOSENANSWER);
                           String Content = Question.getString(TAG_QUESTION_CONTENT);

                           JSONObject Answers = Question.getJSONObject(TAG_ANSWERS);
                           JSONObject Answer = Answers.getJSONObject(TAG_ANSWER);
                           String Content1 = Answers.getString(TAG_ANSWERS_CONTENT);

                             questionList = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();

                               HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();

                               map.put(TAG_QUESTION_SUBJECT, Subject);
                               map.put(TAG_QUESTION_NUMANSWERS, NumAnswers);

                               questionList.add(map);

                           }



                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

                return TAG_RESULTS ; 



        }
        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String file_URL) {

                ListAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(getBaseContext(), questionList,
                        R.layout.listview,
                        new String[] { TAG_QUESTION_SUBJECT, TAG_QUESTION_NUMANSWERS }, new int[] {
                        R.id.Subject, R.id.NumAnswers });

                setListAdapter(adapter);

                android.widget.ListView lv = getListView();

                lv.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

                    @Override
                    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1,int arg2, long arg3) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                    }




                });

            }       
}}
```

JSONParsser Class:

```
public class JSONParsser {

    InputStream is;
    JSONObject jObj;
    String json = "";
    public EditText et;

    public JSONParsser () {
    }

    public JSONObject readJSONFeed(String URL) {

        try{
        HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpPost request = new HttpPost(URL);
        //request.setURI(website);
        try {
            HttpResponse response = client.execute(request);
        HttpEntity httpEntity = response.getEntity();
        is = httpEntity.getContent();

        } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        try {
            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                    is, "iso-8859-1"), 8);
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            String line;
            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                sb.append(line + "\n");
            }
            is.close();
            json = sb.toString();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e("Buffer Error", "Error converting result " + e.toString());
        }

        try {
            jObj = new JSONObject(json);
        } catch (JSONException e) {
           Log.e("JSON Parser", "Error parsing data " + e.toString());
        }

        Log.d("JSON String",json);

        return jObj;

        }finally{}

    }{
    }}
```

Comment: The cause is very clear.  What did you learn when you Googled for it?  `Caused by: android.view.ViewRootImpl$CalledFromWrongThreadException: Only the original thread that created a view hierarchy can touch its views.`

Comment: I learned that u cannot access UI views from asynctask.. thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can not access any layout items in the asynctask. You are call findViewById for your EditText in doInBackground. In order to get around this, you can place the EditText and searchTerm outside the AsyncTask and set the searchTerm to a final global variable that you'll then be able to access inside your AsyncTask.

Comment: Like this: `final EditText = et;` `final et = searchTerm;`

Comment: Just to clarify EditText = et; final String str = searchTerm; and in the doInBackground use str.

Answer (score 0):

Move this line

```
EditText et = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText1);
```

from `doInBackground()` of your `AsyncTask` to `onCreate()`

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

EditText et;
Button getanswer;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    EditText et = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText1);  //Here

    Button getanswer = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
```

The `UI` can't be updated on a background `Thread` which is where `doInBackground()` runs so you need to initialize your `EditText` outside of the `AsyncTask`

Answer (score 0):

Never update UI from a bacground-thread.

See [AsyncTask](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html)

> When an asynchronous task is executed, the task goes through 4 steps:
>
> **onPreExecute()**, invoked on the UI thread before the task is executed.
>   This step is normally used to setup the task, for instance by showing
>   a progress bar in the user interface.
>
> **doInBackground(Params...)**, invoked on the background thread
>   immediately after onPreExecute() finishes executing. This step is used
>   to perform background computation that can take a long time. The
>   parameters of the asynchronous task are passed to this step. The
>   result of the computation must be returned by this step and will be
>   passed back to the last step. This step can also use
>   publishProgress(Progress...) to publish one or more units of progress.
>   These values are published on the UI thread, in the
>   onProgressUpdate(Progress...) step.
>
> **onProgressUpdate(Progress...)**, invoked on the UI thread after a call
>   to publishProgress(Progress...). The timing of the execution is
>   undefined. This method is used to display any form of progress in the
>   user interface while the background computation is still executing.
>   For instance, it can be used to animate a progress bar or show logs in
>   a text field.
>
> **onPostExecute(Result)**, invoked on the UI thread after the background
>   computation finishes. The result of the background computation is
>   passed to this step as a parameter.